# Cordova Dialogs plugin: window.prompt = navigator.notification.prompt; and the App is frozen / doesn't respond anymore

Tags: android, cordova, prompt, cordova-plugins, galaxy

Anyone had any issues with navigator.notification.prompt so far?

My App gets stuck on Galaxy Note tablet with android 4.1.2 (just doesn't respond anymore and no more code seems to be executed or at least the view is frozen and doesn't respond to any input) as soon as the frollowing line is executed:

```
window.prompt = navigator.notification.prompt;
```

The alert before this line does appear, the alert right after this line does not appear ant the app doesn't respond anymore.

```
window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;
window.confirm = navigator.notification.confirm;
```

are right before `window.prompt = navigator.notification.prompt;` and don't seem to make any problems.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Help would be appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Tell me something, why you nedd to set the `navigator.notification.prompt` in `window.prompt` when you can directly use the first one.

Comment: it allows me to simply call alert(), confirm() and prompt() afterwards...
Got this from a tutorial where they override it if available and fallback are normal browser dialog functions.

But you are right! calling it directly works as expected. Though, would be interesting why it crashes the other way and only for prompt...

Thank you!

Comment: p.s. in other angular modules, "navigator" isn't accessible or I don't know how to access it from there. with the assignment to "window" I can access it without problems from other angular modules...

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you looked in the console logs you would see a message telling you that navigator.notification is undefined.

The reason is that cordova objects are not available untill the deviceready event is fired.

So you have to wait for the deviceready event before you can do your assignments.

In jquery it would be something like this :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",function(){
        window.alert = navigator.notification.alert;
        window.confirm = navigator.notification.confirm;
    },false);
```

Sorry I don't know how you would do with angular or ionic.